# Problem in background transparency on Terminal

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, transparency

I rebooted my computer and after some changes with Ubuntu Tweak on my window manager theme, etc., I came with this problem in my Terminal.
Before the reboot, I could see the things behind the terminal perfectly, but now the transparency seems to be only working with the desktop background (as shown a part in the picture).
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks[image]

Comment: You have a nice problem.

Comment: Same as mine, also searching for the solution.

Comment: [Dishank] Did you have this problem when upgrading your system to work with a Nvidia graphic card? I got my problem when I did it.

Comment: not exactly. I didnt notice how it happens.

Comment: [King Shimkus] I am using a screwed theme. Gtk: Bojo-red and Window Theme: Bojo-greyscale. Now I am using Ambience but the problem stills.

Comment: When you reply to someone you have to do `@theirname` - e.g. @kingshimkus (no spaces) ^^^. Otherwise they won't be notified.

Comment: @KingShimkus yeah, I know it does - I was alerting you that there was a message for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try clicking on edit --> preferences and select the appearance tab and change the background transparent to **none (solid color)**?

[Background Tab](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-xRC3qapusiM/U9u7if8AhJI/AAAAAAAACos/w-v9erASo_4/s213-p/Screenshot%2B-%2B08012014%2B-%2B11%3A02%3A53%2BAM.png)

[Appearance Tab](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-LGDcagv7AFU/U9u7git9NoI/AAAAAAAACok/2mgs68M4O4s/w212-h213-p/Screenshot%2B-%2B08012014%2B-%2B11%3A02%3A37%2BAM.png)

Comment: I tried but this not watch I am looking for. I want to transparency  background but it only shows my desktop background but not the layers below it.

Comment: Well I do know in 14.04 when you go to Edit -> preference -> Appearance tab and change the background to transparency.  Under there you can move the slider to create a transparency to suit your needs, as well as, you can change your font to be bigger and bolder.  next under the colors tab you can change the Text color, background color, etc... so that you are able to see what you are doing in terminal.  Not sure if that was what you where looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override this terminal setting with **CCSM** (Compiz config settings manager) in *opacity, brightness and saturation* -> *windows specific settings* click new and plus button, chose **window class** and then grab button click on open terminal window and set value e.g 75 for opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity compositing-manager true
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasoning behind this answer?